# what font property does 400 represent within the context of the code below?

Tags: css

I'm new to CSS and I'm trying to learn the concept of font. I am confused by what font property 400 represents? When I changed it, the content within the body appear to be smaller, but I don't know what it really does?

```
body { 
       background: #FFF; 
       font: 400 1.5em/1.5 "Droid Serif", serif; 
       color: #111;
       text-align: center;
       height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`font` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/#font-prop) is a shorthand of [`font-style`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/#propdef-font-style), [`font-variant`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/#propdef-font-variant), [`font-weight`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/#propdef-font-weight), [`font-stretch`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/#propdef-font-stretch), [`font-size`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/#propdef-font-size), [`line-height`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-line-height) and [`font-family`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/#propdef-font-family).

Among those, the only properties which can accept `400` as its value are `font-weight` and `line-height`. But in the `font` value, the `line-height` one, if any, must be prefixed with `/`.

Then, `400` is the value of `font-weight`, which is the same as `normal`.

```css
font-weight: 400; /* Same as `font-weight: normal` */
```

This is the gradation of the numerical values acceptable by `font-weight`:

```
100 - Thin
200 - Extra Light (Ultra Light)
300 - Light
400 - Normal
500 - Medium
600 - Semi Bold (Demi Bold)
700 - Bold
800 - Extra Bold (Ultra Bold)
900 - Black (Heavy)
```

Since `400` is equivalent to the initial value of `font-weight`, you can remove it.

Answer (score 1):

It's the font weight. The larger the value, the "bolder" the font. 400 is "normal", while "bold" would be 700 for instance.